# Does `viewScript` in `block.json` actually enqueue a js file?

Tags: block-editor

If I have declared, `viewScript` in my block.json file. Do I need to enqueue the script manually within my `register_block_type();` function also? (I didn't think it was necessary for 5.9?)

**My Block.json**

```
"textdomain": "postcode-pricing-wizard",
"editorScript": "file:./index.js",
"viewScript": "file:./view.js",
"style": "file:./style-index.css"
```

**My Problem**

I've enqueued the script, as shown above, I can see a completed build directory and I can also see my block within the editor.

`view.js` However, isn't loading for me on my front-end? I'm not too sure why?

Unless I've misinterpreted the doc's [Block Editor Handbook - Metadata](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-metadata/#view-script)

```
{ "viewScript": "file:./build/view.js" }

// Block type frontend script definition. 
// It will be enqueued only when viewing the content on the front of the site.
// Since WordPress 5.9.0 (My WP Version - 5.9)
```

--

Here's my `register_block_type()` function just in case it's needed.

```
register_block_type( PPW_DIR_PATH . '/build/pricing-wizard-block/',
    array(
        'render_callback' => function( $attributes, $content ) {
            if(!is_admin()) {
                wp_localize_script( 'wp-block-ppw-postcode-pricing-wizard-js', 'data', ['ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')]);
            }

            ob_start();
            include_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/includes/block-editor/pricing-wizard-block/views' . '/block.php';
            return ob_get_clean();
        },
    )
);
```

Comment: this too would be my expectation. I do notice you're trying to localise the `admin-ajax.php` files location, is there a reason you chose to use the legacy AJAX API instead of the modern REST API for AJAX actions? Are you using v5.9?

Comment: @TomJNowell I chose the legacy version for ease of use. I'm more familiar with that version. I plan on revising in due course, but for now, I'm favouring speed in this particular project. I am currently using v5.9 yes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Note to self, rest-up and re-read the docs.**

So it turns out that the answer **is written in the docs**, but rather obscurely. If you check out the [Frontend Enqueueing](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-metadata/#frontend-enqueueing) section of the Block Editor Handbook, you'll see this statement.

```
Frontend Enqueueing #Frontend Enqueueing
Starting in the WordPress 5.8 release, it is possible to instruct WordPress to enqueue scripts and styles for a block type only when rendered on the frontend. It applies to the following asset fields in the block.json file:

- script
- viewScript (when the block defines render_callback during registration in PHP, then the block author is responsible for enqueuing the script)
- style
```

As it turns out I have defined a `render_callback` so I do need to manually enqueue my `view.js` script.

You know when you're just that tired you get tunnel vision. Yeah, this was one of those times. Anyway, thanks for reading. Figured I'd answer for anyone else that came along with a similar issue.

Comment: It seems that this is true, removing render_callback enqueues the script defined in viewScript. I just don't get what is reasoning behind that behavior?

Comment: Yes, I've also miss looked that one at first :) One thing that still confuses me, is why are my scripts loaded in the front-end even if the block is not there? I thought it will be loaded conditionally.

Comment: The name of the script registered is going to be what you call the block (`name` in `block.json`) + `-view-script`
e.g.
`"name": "my-blocks/snazzy-block",`.

So in your callback function:
`wp_enqueue_script( 'my-blocks-snazzy-block-view-script' );`

Answer (score 7):

EVEN NEWER EDIT: I actively participated as contributor in changing this rule. Starting from WordPress 6.1, viewScript **will** enqueue javascript even for dynamic blocks.

See [trac #56470](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/56470).

EDIT: I spoke yesterday with WP developers, viewScript does not actually **enqueue** script, but only **registers** it.

The reason is that in `render_callback` you might conclude that script is not necessary and not enqueue it. So, only for **dynamic blocks**, viewScript registers the script, while you must enqueue it in `render_callback`. For regular React blocks, script is automatically enqueued.

---

I tested this with WordPress 5.9.3 and @wordpress/scripts 22.5.0 and script does get enqueued. I think the original error was `"viewScript": "file:./build/view.js"` in block.json. Block.json should be placed in src directory, together with view script and they are copied in the build process to build directory. Afterwards, block is initialized from build directory.

i.e. for dynamic block `logos` (it has php for front end showing)

```php
...
require 'logos/src/index.php';
register_block_type( "$dir/logos/build",
    ['render_callback' => 'render_logos'] );
...
```

in block.json:

```json
...
"editorScript": "file:index.js",
"editorStyle": "file:index.css",
"style": "file:style-index.css",
"viewScript": "file:logos-front.js",
...
```

Comment: If you have a multi-block plugin you can just create multiple folders in the src and wp-scripts will compile them automatically into separated folders. I'm using wp-scripts 22.5.0 and have a multi-directory plugin.

Comment: @Alexander - thanks for comment. It did not work a year ago. I'll try this and if it works, I will update my answer

Comment: @Lovor awesome to hear this has been changed. Thanks for contributing to this. 

Comment: For me, experience with WordPress developing community was a good one so far. It really feels like it is a community project, and if you think something should be improved and you have good reasons for this, or you have a bugfix, you can contribute and this really works!

Comment: @Lovor Thank you for getting out of bed, contributing to Gutenberg and, for taking the time to return to update your OP. Not all programmers wear capes

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, but it was because my `wp script build` and `wp script start` used a custom entry point.

I had to add my viewScript manually to the build/start commands as in this example. Then in `block.json` I pointed the viewScript to the build folder, and it began enqueuing automatically:

`"build:custom": "wp-scripts build index.js view.js --output-path=build"`